# Zoom and pan in a Tkinter canvas

Tags: python, graphics, tkinter

I'm a beginner programmer, so please don't be harsh if my question is too basic.
I wrote a simple code in Python where I've got a canvas object 500X500 px, defined as:

`t=Canvas(top,height=500,width=500,bg="white")`

The program generates a picture in the canvas, which always fits into it, but some details are too small, hence I'd like to add a feature: the user should be able to zoom in the picture (by clicking on it, for instance), and to move around by holding down the mouse and dragging or by using some additional scrollbars. Could you please suggest me how to do it, or where to look? On the web I've only found complex examples with classes and other advanced stuff I don't know and, at the moment, I don't need.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide the entire code?